# Delete all animation Keys using MAXScript in 3ds Max globally

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am trying to use MAXScript to delete all animation Keys from my scene using MAXScript. At the moment I am using the mouse and pressing CTRL + A to select all objects thus bringing up the keys for all objects in my scene. I am then selecting all Keys on the animation timeline using my mouse, and then selecting all keys on the timeline, and then deleting them. How do I do it in MAXScript?

I have found this in the [MAXScript documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/index.html?url=files/GUID-B1700B1D-B1EA-4A6C-B4A3-A29DB26C8C0-1357.htm,topicNumber=d28e512291), but I don't know how to use it:

```
deleteKeys <controller> [#allKeys | #selection]
```

I tried using

```
deleteKeys globaltracks #allKeys
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a method I posted as part of [this](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?f=98&t=1020938) challenge on [CGTalk](http://forums.cgsociety.org). I've modified it to delete all keys on animated controllers. It manipulates the built-in Trackbar custom filter functions to automatically iterate all controllers of all objects, instead of having to retrieve all controllers youself.

```
(   
fn filterCallbackFunction theAnimatable theParent theSubAnimIndex theGrandParent theNode = 
(       
    if isController theAnimatable do deleteKeys theAnimatable #allKeys
    true
)

with redraw off
(   
    trackbar.filter = #all
    local filtind = maxops.trackbar.registerFilter filterCallbackFunction undefined "." 1 active:on
    disableRefMsgs()
    local sel = getCurrentSelection()
    select objects
    maxops.trackbar.redraw forceRedraw:on
    maxops.trackbar.unregisterfilter filtind        
    select sel
    enableRefMsgs()
    ok
)
)
```

Edit: Sorry, or just use this :)

```
deleteKeys objects #allKeys
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max select all
macros.run "Animation Tools" "DeleteSelectedAnimation"
clearSelection()
```

or drag this code to a toolbar to make a macro!

Comment: Welcome LoneRobot, and thanks for the constructive answer. I would mod up if I would know if it was correct (reviewing first time answers, not an expert on this).

Answer (score 1):

OR to just delete keys from a limited group of objects try

```
for o in objects where matchpattern o.name pattern:"*somename*" do deleteKeys o #allKeys
```

or select the objects to delete keys from and try this

```
for o in selection do deletekeys o #allkeys
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to delete all keys using this command:

```
deletekeys $*.controller #allkeys
```

Comment: How can I use this on camera&cameraTarget?

Comment: `deletekeys camera.controller #allkeys` ? Could also be something like `deletekeys camera.position.controller #allkeys` but its has been a while since I did not touch 3ds max.

Answer (score 0):

Without scripting: Hit Ctrl-A, then Main Menu > Animation > Delete selected animation